# Bind an array of objects without specifying the array indexes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages page, and want to submit an array of objects and automatically bind them.

However, these objects will be edited (added, edited and deleted) on the client side. So rather than specify the index of each array item (`name=Ship.Products[1].ProductId`), it would be much easier to omit the index (`name=Ship.Products[].ProductId`).

However, Razor Pages does not appear to recognize the data without the array index.

###### Models

```
public class EditShipViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Shipper { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    [DisplayName("Port of Origin")]
    public string PortOfOrigin { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Is Empty")]
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ETA")]
    public DateTime? Eta { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Departure { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EditShipProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}

public class EditShipProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Inbound Quantity")]
    public double InboundQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

###### Property

```
[BindProperty]
public EditShipViewModel Ship { get; set; }
```

###### Markup

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody id="ship-products">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[].Id" type="hidden" value="1">
                <input name="Ship.Products[].ProductId" type="hidden" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="1000">
            </td>
            <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[].Id" type="hidden" value="2">
                <input name="Ship.Products[].ProductId" type="hidden" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="2000">
            </td>
            <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[].Id" type="hidden" value="3">
                <input name="Ship.Products[].ProductId" type="hidden" value="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="3000">
            </td>
            <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>
```

Is there any way to have Razor Pages binding recognize this markup as an array of objects?

###### Update

Here's the actual data posted to my page.

[image]

Comment: FYI both `x[1]` and `x.1` should work. If you don't want to care about sequential indexes, maybe bind to a dictionary instead. eg `name="Ship.Products[{Id}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, these objects will be edited (added, edited and deleted) on
> the client side

If you want to avoid failing model binding due to the index of  array item not numbered sequentially starting at zero

You may try  replace the index of array and add a input with the name `Ship.Products.index` as below. This is known as an *explicit* index:

```
 <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="Ship.Products[a].Id" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <input name="Ship.Products[a].ProductId" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <input name="Ship.Products.index" type="hidden" value="a">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Ship.Products[a].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="1000">
                </td>
                <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="Ship.Products[b].Id" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <input name="Ship.Products[b].ProductId" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <input name="Ship.Products.index" type="hidden" value="b">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Ship.Products[b].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="1000">
                </td>
                <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; No.

You can bind a collection of simple values like `name=1&name=2&name=3` to `int[] name`. But there's no way this can work with complex objects, as the server would have no logical way to tell when one item stops and another begins.

If you don't want to worry about posting sequential values, then you can bind a `Dictionary<int,T>` instead of a `List<T>`. That way the client can generate new dictionary keys, but can also remove them without needing to renumber everything else.

```cs
public IDictionary<int, EditShipProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
```

```html
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[23].Id" type="hidden" value="1">
                <input name="Ship.Products[23].ProductId" type="hidden" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[23].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="1000">
            </td>
            <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[42].Id" type="hidden" value="2">
                <input name="Ship.Products[42].ProductId" type="hidden" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Ship.Products[42].InboundQuantity" type="hidden" value="2000">
            </td>
            <td class="text-end">[Edit][Delete]</td>
        </tr>
```

As a side effect, this approach works well with preserving user supplied values in `ModelState` when re-rendering the same template, even if the user supplied data failed to parse.

Comment: Seems like binding to a dictionary still carries some of the same issues. For example, if I am adding a new item on the client, I need to figure out which indexes are already in use so that I can use a unique index.

Comment: Sure, but that's not too complicated. `<script>var lastId = @Model.Ship.Products.Keys.Max();</script>`